# Effects of resultset and statements not being closed in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have a java application where on thread is the socket connection which captures data and pass on to another thread for databaprocessing using the producer and consumer concept by putting into the queue. The problem is that database processing thread at times fail to run and I notice that there are some of resultset and statement have not been closed. Can this be the reason for it to fail and or is there any other reason. How I know it fail is using the isAlive method to check on the database processing thread which shows no value means is dead.

Snippet of my codes.

```
private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> databaseQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
class DatabaseProcessor implements Runnable {
  public void run()
      {
      try 
      {
           createConnection();
           while (true) 
             {
                     message = databaseQueue.take();
                     //all the database processing here with multiple queries and resultsets 
             }
       }
       catch (Exception e) 
       {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        try 
        {    
        dbconn.rollback();  
        } 
        catch (Exception rollback) 
        {    
            rollback.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }           
       }

     }
 }
```

Comment: As to the question in the title: resource leaking (i.e. the other side will run out of them and not be able anymore to provide them). As to the question in the body: no idea, based on the information given so far. At least, you should **always** close resources after use. This has nothing to do with multithreading.

Comment: Are multiple threads using the same database connection?  That's not allowed.  You should use a connection pool if this is the case.

Comment: @Gray no this only one thread which gets data in a queue and will keep processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who knows without looking at all of your code?

Failing to close scarce resources of all kinds, not just those associated with databases, eventually manifests itself in exhaustion and unavailability.  Connections to databases are finite.  Result sets are cursors, which are also limited.

You should close resources in the scope of the method in which they were created.  Acquire them *in a try block* and close them in a finally block, wrapped in individual try/catch blocks.

Comment: some of the resultset are in inner loops so now after finish reading the values I just put a try and catch and close there itself is that better solution?

Comment: *"Acquire them and close them in a finally block..."* I suspect you meant *"Acquire them **in a try block** and close them in a finally block..."* :-)

Comment: @tj no some is within other while loop so I acquire in the while loop and close it there itself because the resultset is local variable here.

Comment: Sounds wrong...put the while in the try block.  You should be using a PreparedStatement if you're looping.

Comment: @duffymo yes I think I should do that maybe that part is having some exception and not being caught right? Should I put even the createConnection inside it too?

Comment: No, you should not create a connection in a loop.  Create the connection, use it, then close it.

Comment: @duffymo I create the connection once outside the while loop and I keep using it for ever. The reason I need this is to maintain the update and insert into the db according to what the socket connection receives.

Comment: @duffymo as per your suggestion I remove everything and put them in a big try and catch even the while loop. Unfortunately my db thread is dead without any exception.

Comment: @What could be wrong I have already closed all the resultset and statements properly yet the same. Could it be a logical problem here?

Comment: No, you're assuming that it's the root cause of your issue but it's something else.

Comment: @duffymo yes you are right that is something why I would say that is because I got a previous of the codes which works perfectly fine even without closing the resultset and statement. So when I added some long new codes is causing this. So I guess the cause is in this new codes then.

Comment: Closing resources is still a good thing.  I'm betting that part of your problem is "long new codes".  It's not decomposed well.  You need to think more carefully about how to decompose this complex problem into smaller pieces that you can test in isolation and then reassemble to solve the larger problem.

Comment: @duffymo yes I will do the closing part too. Now what I doing is adding small pieces of code and then run to see if the thread is dead. So that is only way I can test. Thank you very much. Beside that how is the idea of consumer n producer in my case here is it ok to have this type of threading.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt that the `resultSet` and `statement` not being closed is the reason why it is failing.  I suspect that it is a symptom of the problem.  Some part of the data processing on one of the threads is throwing an exception and the database connections are not being closed.

- Make sure you are appropriately logging all of your exceptions.
- You should do the closing of the connections in the same thread as the one that opened them if you can.  That's a good pattern.
- Make sure that you have `try { .. } finally { close database connections... }` code around your exceptions.  That will make sure that they get closed.

Comment: I added a snippet of code for my db thread in my question. I create only one connection and is shared. So in the db thread it will keep getting data from the queue added by the other thread and process here. Thus I do not have a final for my db close but  just before the try closing I close some of resultset and statement is that fine?

Comment: just to add so far I have check the log no exception indicating resultset or statement not close which is why I am lost and could not determine what is the exact cause the thread fails?